# Dynamic library not linking on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, ldd

I am using following makefile

```
SHELL    = /bin/sh
CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
TARGET   = product_bridge.so

MYPRODUCT    = /tmp/product
JAVASDK  = /x86.linux/include/
CXXFLAGS += -I$(JAVASDK) -I$(JAVASDK)/linux -I$(GFCPP)/include -Wl,-rpath, -L$(MYPRODUCT)/lib -lmyproduct

SOURCES = $(shell echo *.cpp)
HEADERS = $(shell echo *.h)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -shared $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

clean:
    rm -rf *.so *.o
```

When I build this on `ubuntu` i do not see `myproduct` in `ldd`. But I am doing the same on `RHEL` I see `myproduct` in `ldd`

My Shared library i.e. `product_bridge.so` is build on `RHEL`

Comment: Do you have some `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ? And the `-Wl,-rpath,` in your `CXXFLAGS` is suspicious (since followed by a space): the linker `ld` wants an `-rpath` followed by a directory. Maybe you want `-Wl,-rpath,.` or something else...

Comment: Yes I have LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but does not work

Comment: It looks like you're picking up the library libmyproduct.a or libmyproduct.so from `/tmp/product`. Do you have that library at the same location on both the machines ?